# Which comic series aligns most closely with Netflix's Daredevil series?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil, daredevil-2015

I really like the gritty and dark tone of the Netflix Daredevil series. Admittedly, I haven't read much of the Daredevil comics but the various issues I have seemed more light-hearted and a completely different tone.

Can someone tell me which series/volume is the closest match to the TV show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overall most of the Daredevil series is original but keeping in the same trend as the comics. The most direct comic comparison is Frank Miller's run. Miller introduced the black proto-costume, and Murdock's mentor Stick. It's pretty easy to find a copy of that particular run of comics as Miller's work is quite popular. I hope this helps.